# Link dialog may appear while voting on question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, hyperlinks

When I click on a vote button on a question, the link dialog containing a URL to the question may appear intermittently.  This most often occurs on Stack Exchange Photography, but I've seen it occur on other sites.  Is this a bug?

Comment: Nope, it's a feature

Comment: Yup, I've seen this too - I've yet to establish what the pattern is though.

Comment: I don't think the pattern is public. I remember Jeff talking about it here on meta somewhere, but can't find it.

Comment: Anything like this that may be subject to gaming is best kept secret.  You comments have convinced me that this is by design.  Thanks!

Comment: @fretje At most, Jeff just mentioned that it stops once you've made enough promotions to posts.

Comment: @Grace: Yep, now you mention it, that was what I remembered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't a bug.  It is a feature.  The dialog (if you read it!) invites you to share the link.  As you've voted on the question, you must think it is a good question, one worthy of, perhaps, sharing!  (:

There is a random chance you will be invited to do so.